# Can Java Logger output not get written if an Exception occurs immediately after Log.info call?

Tags: java, logging

I am reading through some code and comparing what I see in production log file content but am concerned that maybe I am not looking at what is really in production ( yes, I know ... )

I expect to see a string from a log.info() call but it is immediately before a database update that may be the culprit of an SQLException.

Is it possible that the exception could mask the logger output ? I.E. execution has terminated before flushing the log output buffer ?

If that is not the case I will need to figure out some other reason for the info not being written.

Comment: What logging platform? `java.util.logging.logger`?

Comment: And how is it configured?

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible. When you write down something using log.into(),log.error(),log.debug(),log.wran(),log.fatal(),log.trace() methods, it holds content to write down in the log file.

To get more detail you can catch the exception and print that stacktrace using log.error(). You can easily diagnostic the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `java.util.logging` logging framework uses shutdown hooks to make sure the `flush()` method is called on its [`handlers`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Handler.html). Provided the handler properly implements the flush() method to flush the cached logs to disk, it will work. The handlers provided with the java api do implement this.

It can be verified in [the source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/logging/LogManager.java#258) that it uses shutdown hooks.